# Loading data into html5 canvas roullete using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to load data into the html5 canvas roulette which I found here:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas

I added another button called loader which will load the data from a php file. The data is an array of names. I then assigned it to the people array. Then called the drawRouletteWheel(). The drawRouletteWheel uses the data from the people array.

```
var people = [];
    $('#loader').click(function(){
        $.post('loader.php', function(data){
            people = data;
            drawRouletteWheel();

        });
    });
```

The loader.php file just loads random records fetched from mysql database:

```
$select_random = $db->get_results("SELECT people FROM tbl_people ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12");
    if(!empty($select_random)){
        foreach($select_random as $k=>$v){
            $data[] = $v->people;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Something is actually being loaded into the roulette but it seems to be incomplete. And firebug is also returning something:
[image]

What do I need to do here?It seems like the data that was returned from the php file isn't being treated as an array.

Comment: thanks! it works. I never thought I still need to parse it.

Comment: Sorry about that, the comment was a stopgap while I typed up a proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that is returned from the php page is treated as a string, so you are getting individual letters as javascript gets the character at each index.

To fix this:

```
var people = [];
    $('#loader').click(function(){
        $.post('loader.php', function(data){
            people = $.parseJSON(data);
            drawRouletteWheel();
    });
});
```